# Saving checkbox state to cookie without clicking

Tags: jquery, cookies, checkbox

I use this to store the state of my checkboxes

```
$("input.box").each(function() {
    var mycookie = $.cookie($(this).attr('name'));
    if (mycookie && mycookie == "true") {
        $(this).prop('checked', mycookie);
    }
});
$("input.box").change(function() {
    $.cookie($(this).attr("name"), $(this).prop('checked'), {
        path: '/',
        expires: 365
    });
});
```

And I use this in a new function to check one of my checkboxes:

```
if(code18 == 092) {
    $(".validate-status").text("Correct!");
    $('#code18correct').show();
    $('input[name=code18box]').prop('checked', true);
}
```

It works, it checks the box, but the problem is, because I didn't click it, it doesn't save it to cookie. Can't think of how to fix this.

Anybody?

Comment: `code18 == 092` - the leading 0 would make this an octal number if it didn't contain that `9`. Better get rid of the leading 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the checkbox's `change` handler after setting its `checked` property:

```
$('input[name=code18box]').prop('checked', true).change();
// which is the same as
$('input[name=code18box]').prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
```

Or a better performance-wise version using [`.triggerHandler()`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/):

```
$('input[name=code18box]').prop('checked', true).triggerHandler('change');
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was trying, but couldn't get it to work, thank you very much!!