# saving and re-applaying checkbox list in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

So I have dropdown list and multiple checkboxes in div

Checkboxes list populates on  change of dropdown list

I want to save checked checkboxes so I could reapply them

I managed to serialize checked checkboxes

```
 $("#category").change(function() {
    var formData = $(this).parents('form').serialize();
    var checked = $('.check input:checkbox:checked').serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/test/hardwares/getByCategory',
        type: 'Post',
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
            $('.check').html(data);
                        }
    });
});
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: If you select A from the drop down, then select B from drop down before reverting to A, will you get the same checkbox options for A? Or will you get new choices?

Comment: If I select from dropdown A I get check options for A if I go to B a get options for B and If I go back to A I get same options from first select. So, no new choices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/Q4Gyq/

HTML

```
<select id="sel">
    <option value="0">A class</option>
    <option value="1">B class</option>    
</select>

<div id="opts">
    Food: <input type="checkbox" id="ifood" value="food" class="0 1" />
    Water: <input type="checkbox" id="iwater" value="water" class="0 1"/>
    Cable TV: <input type="checkbox" id="itv" value="tv" class="1" style="display: none" />
    Elevator: <input type="checkbox" id="ielev" value="elevator" class="1" style="display: none" />
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function stateManager(optsDiv){
    var _optsWrapper  = '';
    var _states       = {};
    var _currentState = null;

    var construct = function(optsDiv){
        _optsWrapper = optsDiv;
    }

    this.setStateId = function(stateId){
        _currentState = stateId;
    }

    this.save = function(stateToSet){
        _states[_currentState] = [];

        var checkedCheckBoxes = $(_optsWrapper).find('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
        for(var i = 0; i < checkedCheckBoxes.length; i++){
            _states[_currentState].push($(checkedCheckBoxes[i]).attr('id'));
        }

        this.setStateId(stateToSet);
    }

    this.getState = function(stateId){
        return _states[stateId] ? _states[stateId] : [];
    }

    construct(optsDiv);
}

window.onload = function(){
    var manager = new stateManager('#opts');
    manager.setStateId($('#sel').val());

    $('#sel').on('change', function(){
        manager.save(this.value);

        //extra functionality {
        filterCheckboxes(this.value);
        clearStates();
        //extra functionality }

        var state = manager.getState(this.value);        
        for(var i = 0; i < state.length; i++){
            $('#' + state[i]).prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
}

function filterCheckboxes(cls){
    var checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');
    for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
        $(checkboxes[i]).hasClass(cls) ? $(checkboxes[i]).show() : $(checkboxes[i]).hide();
    }
}

function clearStates(){
    var checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
    for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
        $(checkboxes[i]).prop('checked', false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it kind of depends on exactly what you want to do, do you need to save the state of the checkboxes permanently, i.e. to a database so they are available whenever the user comes to your site, or more temporarily, like on a session basis?

Permanently, you would need to post your serialized array back to your site (possibly with another $.ajax command)

Temporarily, you could save the state of checkboxes to a cookie on the users machine, and apply the state on the next page similar to this post

[Saving checkbox state to cookie without clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094975/saving-checkbox-state-to-cookie-without-clicking)

Comment: I need store them temporaly but i would like to skip cookies if possible

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to copy the checkbox options into a hidden div somewhere outside the form. I tried writing it up as a paragraph, but it was just a lot of "choices" and "options", so here is some pseudo-pseudo-code

```
$("#dropdown").change( function() {

    var checkboxStash = $("#checkboxStash");   // a hidden container located
                                               // outside the form

    var checkboxSection = $("#checkboxes");    // the checkbox section in
                                               // your form

    // Grab all the current options
    var oldOptions = $(checkboxSection).html();

    // Stash the old options
    if( oldOptions are in stash) {
        replace them
    } else {
        add them to stash
    }

    // Clear the checkbox section
    $(checkboxSection).html("");

    // Check if the new category's checkboxes have been stashed
    var newOptions = $("#check-newCategory");

    if (newOptions exists) {
        checkboxSection.html(newOptions);
    } else {
        fetch the options from the server
    }
});
```

The benefits are two-fold: You preserve the users selections and by caching the checkbox options you save time by eliminating unnecessary requests.